# Get websites title and description, save to utf8 table, php/mysql

Tags: php

I've been trying today all day to figure this out and I have no idea.

What I want:
Get the title and meta description of any kind of website.

Save this info to utf table in mysql.

What the problem is?
Different sites have different charsets which results in that some have chinese, some contain umlauts (german), then we have russian and so on..

I've tried preg_match which works for some while not for others, i've tried DOMdocument which is the same as preg_match.

Is there any class available that will do this?

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: In what way is DOMDocument the same as preg_match? Do you mean they're similar in the fact that they're both not working for you? DOMDocument parses an entire xml doc which you can then navigate through. preg_match just performs regex on a string.

Comment: Use Curl and explode function and you will be able to do it easily.

Comment: You missed the point. But with both you can extract the required info.

Forget about what I've said I used, the point is to get title and meta description in ANY language and save it to table.

Comment: I do use Curl to get the pages source. But then the problem is saving this info to table.

To give an example, get me the title of this websites and save it to table:

http://www.baidu.com/
http://www.yandex.ru/

Amongst others..

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = file_get_contents( $url );
if( preg_match( '#title>([^<]+?)</title#', $data, $match ) ) {
    $result['title'] = $match[1];
}
if( preg_match( '#name="description"[^>]+?content=('|")([^"']+?)#i', $data, $match ) ) {
    $result['description'] = $match[2];
}
```

not tested! just wrote it down quickly - print_r the match's to see what exactly they match etc.

set your mysql table to latin1 - that should be fine with all kinds of languages. - i never took care of it because it works 99% of the time.

Comment: Doesn't work, the regexp..

Also tried with latin1 charset, it also doesn't work.